# Can PER (aligned or unaligned) be used to describe encoding/decoding of any arbitrary octet sequence?

Tags: asn.1

I am currently reading the specs for ASN.1 and the various encoding rules, and I understand most of them are designed so that you first design your PDU semantics and then encode it using *ER to make your PDU "transportable" (deliverable through a given transport)

All of the encoding rules seem to tag types into the resulting octet sequence, except PER.

So my question is: given an existing PDU format (e.g. a 24-bit Windows BMP file), is it possible to use ASN.1 for describing (typing and naming) the fields and use PER to get structured data from the file?

If so, what are the limitations of this approach? (Like endianness, supporting "chooser" fields, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Laurent.

Is it possible? That's debatable. Is it wise? Well...as St Paul says in his letter to the Corinthians, all things are lawful, but not all things are helpful.

As a rule, it's pretty hard to shoehorn an existing file format into PER. It isn't impossible, but unless the format of the file has fixed-length fields (or limits on the size), you're going to have a hard time.

The reason is because PER uses a bit-packed format with a preamble to cover optional and default elements and, when needed, length information. [An example can be found here.](http://www.obj-sys.com/blog/?p=238) (Disclosure: I once used to work for Objective Systems, whose blog is referenced at the link.)

Looking at the [Wikipedia entry on the BMP file structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#File_structure), it appears that there are some optional and semi-optional (?) elements whose presence isn't indicated by anything resembling a PER preamble. This means that a standard PER encoding wouldn't be compatible with the BMP format.

What you *could* do is to try to represent each piece of the BMP structure by individual pieces of ASN.1, generate the components using your preferred tool, and then link them together using custom logic.

With respect to endianness, ASN.1 is designed to solve the problem by standardizing the encoding across the wire. Normally tools—runtime libraries and code generators—will handle whatever you need to worry about under the covers.

For my money, it's probably not worth pursuing an ASN.1 solution here unless you already have some experience with it (and a codebase that could use this approach). You're probably better off using an existing image library in your programming language of choice instead.

Comment: Thank you. The wisdom of the approach does not need to be questioned if it is not feasible to begin with. The BMP format was just an example out of the blue, an instance of "arbitrary" in the title of the question. If ASN.1 and PER can't be used to describe the BMP format in one go (or possibly with a couple layers of payloads), then it's no use trying to use it that way to describe file formats. If you want to build a tower, first estimate the cost.

Comment: No offense intended; sorry if the post came across poorly. The short of it is that PER isn't necessarily suited for arbitrary file formats because it follows regular rules of structure. If you're wedded to ASN.1, [Encoding Control Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encoding_Control_Notation) might be a solution you could use, but most tool support is questionable, and AFAIK there aren't any free ECN compilers.

Comment: No offense taken. Comments are short, so I prefer using the restricted space to convey ideas, not platitudes. No offense intended on my part either. You perfectly answered the question, and it just means "no" :) I will look into ECN. I am mostly interested in the way they approached the problem, not to find a free compiler. Thank you again.